# Saving as ISO/IEC 8859 csv file on Excel or VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv, iso-8859-1, magmi

I am working on a Magento website that uses Magmi for file importing/exporting. Magmi is a software that uses ISO/IEC 8859 (Latin-1) encoding. Since my website in in French, I need special characters to be encoded as ISO/IEC 8859. For example:
"à" becomes "Ã",
"À" becomes "Ã€",
"è" becomes "Ã¨",
etc.

I have to export a .csv file from my .xlsm file, which runs VBA Macros. The csv file has to follow this encoding.

So far, I have tried to use the Replace VBA function for every character. It works, but it is very slow and I have thousands of lines to process multiple times per day. Here is my code:

```
Sub replaceFrenchCharacters()
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Cells
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "à", "Ã")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "À", "Ã€")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "è", "Ã¨")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "È", "Ãˆ")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "ù", "Ã¹")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "Ù", "Ã™")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "â", "Ã¢")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "Â", "Ã‚")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "ê", "Ãª")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "Ê", "ÃŠ")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "î", "Ã®")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "Î", "ÃŽ")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "ô", "Ã´")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "û", "Ã»")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "Û", "Ã›")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "é", "Ã©")
    cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, "É", "Ã‰")
Next
```

End Sub

I have also tried: File > Save As > .csv > Tools > Web Options > US ASCII but it does not seem to work.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Comment: I have updated the original question :)

Answer (score 0):

I know it doesn't completely solve the problem, but the VBA code is more efficient this way:

```
    cell.Value = _
    Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace( _
    Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace( _
    cell.Value, _
    "à", "Ã"), "À", "Ã€"), "è", "Ã¨"), "È", "Ãˆ"), "ù", "Ã¹"), "Ù", "Ã™"), _
    "â", "Ã¢"), "Â", "Ã‚"), "ê", "Ãª"), "Ê", "ÃŠ"), "î", "Ã®"), "Î", "ÃŽ"), _
    "ô", "Ã´"), "û", "Ã»"), "Û", "Ã›"), "é", "Ã©"), "É", "Ã‰")
```